# Help me how to find the limit. In this case something is strange.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, functions

A fn(x) is a sequence of function.

fn:[0,1]→R defined by fn(x) = n(1-x)  × x^n.

And I want to know limit of this function as n→∞.

In my opinion we can see this like this n(1-x) × x^n.

So as n→∞, lim fn(x) = lim n(1-x)  × lim x^n 
                     = ∞  ×  0
                     = 0

Comment: The answer is indeed identically $0$. We need a separate argument for $x=1$. And this $\infty\times 0$ stuff is in general wrong. You need to use the fact that if $0\le x\lt 1$, $nx^n$ approaches $0$, basically because $x^n$ goes to $0$ much faster than $n$ blows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for pointwise convergence. First, consider endpoints.  $f_n(0) = n(1-0)(0)^n = 0$.  $f_n(1) = n(1-1)(1)^n = 0$.  So, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(0) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(1) = 0$.  Next, consider when $0<x<1$.  First, let's rewrite the function so it is easier to determine the limit.

$n(1-x)x^n = n(1-x)e^{\ln x^n} = n(1-x)e^{n\ln x}$

For all $0<x<1$, $\ln x<0$.  So, as $n\to \infty$, $e^{n\ln x} \to 0$.  We can rewrite this again:

$n(1-x)e^{n\ln x} = (1-x)\dfrac{n}{e^{-n\ln x}}$

Now, as $n\to \infty$, the numerator and denominator both approach infinity.  So, you can apply L'Hospital's Rule.

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}(1-x)\dfrac{n}{e^{-n\ln x}} = (1-x)\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{-e^{-n\ln x}\ln x} = (1-x)(0) = 0$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.